Spring Boot Using Old DB Function Logic
I have a function in my Postgre DB that get's called by a Spring boot application. Inside the function's code there is a FOR UPDATE lock on certain rows. Under certain circumstances this lock caused the System to go into starvation (Some transactions are hogging the locks so incoming threads from spring trying to acquire a connection time out). Due to this, I decided to remove the FOR UPDATE lock from the functions code. This was done without shutting down or restarting the application, the expectation was that the code should update on the fly.
For some reason, however, this function is still locking rows exclusively and causing starvation. I restarted the spring app suspecting that somehow spring is caching the old version of the function.
My question - is it possible that spring is caching/calling the old version of the function with the locking logic? See code below:
DECLARE
    VARIABL_1 bigint;
    VARIABL_2 bigint;
    VARIABL_3 varchar;
BEGIN
    IF "INPUT_1" <= 0 THEN
        RETURN -1;
    END IF;
    
    SELECT "COLUMN_1" INTO VARIABL_1 FROM TABL_EXAMPLE WHERE COLUMN_2 = "INPUT_1" ORDER BY INCREMENT_ID LIMIT 1 **FOR UPDATE**;

    -- Some more basic code logic here. Normal selects, if statements blah blah.

    RETURN 0;
END;


I removed the FOR UPDATE lock from the function code with the expectation that it should resolve the starvation problem. It did not. Locks are still occurring after the FOR UPDATE was removed.
